# How to extend the HTML intellisense in Razor view of ASP.NET Core

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

[image]
We are working on an ASP.NET Core project, and developing a front-end framework, it has a set of markup, similar to HTML or XML, so in .cshtml file, VS treats it as HTML.

My question is whether I can extend the HTML IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2015, so it can display available markups in our framework (e.g. Panel, HBox, etc.) as well as their attributes (e.g. caption, editable, etc.)?

We use `<!DOCTYPE html>` in _Layout.cshtml.

Our environment:

- Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 with ASP.NET Core Tooling Preview 2
- ASP.NET Core 1.0 RTM